# Making a IRQ SMP Affinity change permanent

Tags: debian, interrupt, smp

I have to change the smp_affinity of a interrupt permanently. The following code needs to be executed when the server reboots:

```
echo "1" > /proc/irq/152/smp_affinity_list
echo "2" > /proc/irq/151/smp_affinity_list
echo "3" > /proc/irq/150/smp_affinity_list
echo "4" > /proc/irq/149/smp_affinity_list
echo "5" > /proc/irq/148/smp_affinity_list
echo "6" > /proc/irq/147/smp_affinity_list
echo "7" > /proc/irq/146/smp_affinity_list
echo "8" > /proc/irq/145/smp_affinity_list
echo "9" > /proc/irq/144/smp_affinity_list
echo "10" > /proc/irq/143/smp_affinity_list
echo "11" > /proc/irq/142/smp_affinity_list
echo "12" > /proc/irq/141/smp_affinity_list
echo "13" > /proc/irq/140/smp_affinity_list
echo "14" > /proc/irq/139/smp_affinity_list
echo "15" > /proc/irq/138/smp_affinity_list
echo "16" > /proc/irq/137/smp_affinity_list
```

I've added these lines to the /etc/rc.local file but the changes are not applied to the system. I've also added echo "test" > /root/test which gets executed properly, so the rc.local file gets executed. The system is running Debian 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

The `rc.local` script should be the last executed on boot. Let's supposed it not running as last in your system, then it might run too early, before `/proc` is even mounted. Or it might be a problem on your modular kernel if the `smp_affinity_list` is managed by a kernel module still not loaded when `rc.local` is run.

So, just change your `rc.local` and check for the existance of `/proc/irq/*/smp_affinity_list` before echoing into it. Otherwise `sleep` for some time and try again and eventually emit an error message via the `logger` command, so that you will be able to read it in `/var/log/syslog`.

Answer (score 1):

You may have irqbalance service loading during startup which would reset anything you have running at startup. [This article](https://www.linuxsecrets.com/affinity-explained-setting-affinity-are-resetting-at-boot-process.html) explains how to stop the `irqbalance` service:

```
service --status-all
chkconfig --list | grep '3:on'
chkconfig irqbalance off
service irqbalance stop
```

And then remove it from the boot runlevel so it won't be restarted on boot:

```
update-rc.d -f irqbalance remove <-- removes from boot process
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You need to:

1) Build the latest version of `irqbalance`. Old versions (up through Ubuntu 15.10!) are buggy and ignore the `--banirq` option.

2) Edit `/etc/default/irqbalance` or `/etc/init/irqbalance.conf` to add `--banirq=<num>`.

3) Add your overrides to `/etc/rc.local`.